# How to block only one UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

In my `iOS` app I currently have 2 `UITextField`s named *usernameTextField* and *pINTextField*. Since one of the two must have a length of 4 digits I have used this code to limit the length of *pINTextField*.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (self.pINTextField.text.length >= 4 && range.length == 0)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Strangely this code also disables *usernameTextField* when the user types 4 digits inside *pINTextField* but I want *usernameTextField* to be "type-able" even after the user have inserted the PIN code.

In other words: I want to limit only one of the two `UITextField`s without limiting the other one.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if sender textField == self.pINTextField

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == self.pINTextField && self.pINTextField.text.length >= 4 && range.length == 0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why would you check for the right text field as the last condition? It should be the 1st condition.

Comment: hi @rmaddy If there is "or" condition it could fail but all conditions are "and", does it make difference?

Comment: As written you needlessly check two conditions every time the delegate is called for another text field. If you check the text field first, you can avoid checking the other conditions when it's the wrong text field.

Comment: @rmaddy from that perspective you are right, will update the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1) If you do not already have IBoutlets defined for your text fields create them.

2) You can then select the desired text field as follows:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (self.pINTextField == textField)
    {
       if (textField.text.length >= 4 && range.length == 0)
       {
           return NO;
       }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Using tags for this purpose is extremely fragile. Somebody may come along in the future and modify the tag of the textfield in the nib not realizing that it is tied to this behavior.

Comment: Good point. Your solution is certainly cleaner than using tags.

Comment: +1 for proper use of `if` statements. This structure makes it much cleaner and clearer, especially if each text field ends up needing different checks.

Comment: FYI - the actual logic to enforce 4 digits was copied from the OP's question but it is wrong. It will fail under various conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Give the text field you want to block a unique tag and check it in your if statement like so:

```
if (textField.tag==666 && textField.text.length >= 4 && range.length == 0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: Either in the user interface builder in Xcode or in your program like this: pINTextField.tag=666;

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the `textField` parameter you get in the delegate callback to figure out which `textField` it is and return appropriately based on that.
It seems you already have pointers to those text fields as properties, so you can do:

```
if (textField == self.pINTextField && ... )
   { ... }
```